# How to redirect from parent route to child route in Angular canActivate guard?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I've got this routes

### AppRouting

```
{
   path: 'user',
   canLoad: [AuthGuard],
   loadChildren: () =>
   import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.PublicUserModule)
}
```

### UserRouting

```
{
    path: '',
    component: PublicUserPageComponent,
    canActivate: [UserPhonesCheckGuard],
    children: [
      /*{
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'check'
      },*/
      {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./account/user-account.module').then(
            (m) => m.PublicUserAccountModule
          )
      },
      {
        path: 'check',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./check/user-check.module').then(
            (m) => m.PublicUserCheckModule
          )
      }
    ]
  }
```

Using UserPhonesCheckGuard depending on some conditions I want to redirect
or to the check or to account children route
but with

```
canActivate() 
    return this.router.parseUrl('/user/check');
  }
```

the browser go nuts :(

What path should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this way;

```js
canActivate() 
    return this.router.parseUrl('/user/check');
}
```

an infinite loop occurs.

Because when you return a `UrlTree` (which is returned by `this.router.parseUrl`) from `canActivate` current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation started.

Since new navigation is going to a sub url (child) of current navigation, `canActivate` guard runs again for the new navigation which in turn causes an infinite loop.

That's why you need a way to detect child navigation in `canActivate` and break the infinite loop. One way of detecting child navigation can be to control the url. Such as;

```js
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  console.log(state.url)

  if(state.url === "/user/check" || state.url === "/user/account") 
    return true;

  if(someCondition) /* here you determine which child to navigate */
    return this.router.parseUrl('/user/check');
  else
    return this.router.parseUrl('/user/account');
}
```

I created a [simple demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnu5hn). In the demo, you can see in the console that `canActivate` runs twice for every navigation. One for the parent navigation and one for the child navigation. Without if condition, parent navigation would run indefinitely.

I hope it helps.